# Unable to instantiate angular form.properties in jasmine unit test

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I have a simple clear method in my component as below. As you can see in the comment, `this.form.reset();` is causing an error in my test. When this line is removed the test succeeds. The error is `// TypeError: Cannot read property 'reset' of undefined`

**myComponent.component.ts**

```
  onClearFilter() {
        this.form.reset(); // TypeError: Cannot read property 'reset' of undefined
        this.search = '';
        this.isAdvanced = false;

        this.filterStateService.clearFilterState(this.filterStateKey);

        // Reset Filter state
        this.filterState = new Filter(this.filterStateKey);
        this.filterStateService.filterStates[this.filterStateKey] = { ...this.filterState };
        this.doFilter();
    }
```

**myComponent.spec.ts**

```
describe('onClearFilter', () => {
    it('makes expected calls', () => {
        const filterStateServiceStub: FilterStateService = fixture.debugElement.injector.get(FilterStateService);
        spyOn(filterStateServiceStub, 'clearFilterState').and.callThrough();
        component.onClearFilter();
        expect(filterStateServiceStub.clearFilterState).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
});
```

I'm new to Unit Testing, but I guess I need to define this.form into my `it()` to allow `reset` to no longer be undefined - how do I do this in my scenario? Thanks

**UPDATE**

I tried...

```
describe('onClearFilter', () => {
    it('makes expected calls', () => {
        const filterStateServiceStub: FilterStateService = fixture.debugElement.injector.get(FilterStateService);
        const form: FormGroup = fixture.debugElement.injector.get(FormGroup);
        component.form = form;
        spyOn(filterStateServiceStub, 'clearFilterState').and.callThrough();
        spyOn(component.form, 'reset').and.callThrough();
        component.onClearFilter();
        expect(component.form.reset).toHaveBeenCalled();
        expect(filterStateServiceStub.clearFilterState).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
});
```

`FormGroup` comes from `ReactiveFormsModule` import, so I tried getting form.reset from that as above but got a new error of...

```
Error: StaticInjectorError(DynamicTestModule)[FormGroup]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[FormGroup]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for FormGroup!
```

Based on the above I then added `FormGroup` to my providers but this came up with its own issues and upon reading you dont do that as everything is available from the `ReactiveFormsModule` import.

Comment: Do you create `this.form` in some other method in your service?

Comment: No it doesn't. I have updated my question, and tried something that didnt work but might trigger somebody to help further.

Comment: What I meant was - where you did you initialised it - `this.form = ...`  in your service